# Why does workbox-webpack-plugin prepend "auto" to all asset paths? (resulting in 404's when the app starts up)

Tags: webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

Workbox is driving me bananas. When my app starts, all precached routes return http404, because the workbox InjectManifest plugin appears to prepend **"auto"** to all the cached urls. I have to idea why it does this. I've tried re-installing npm packages, running in incognito, clearing all caches, etc.

I run the application with "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open", and I get the following warning, which might be part of the problem:

```
WARNING in InjectManifest has been called multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.
```

I don't know why I get this error, because I have set watch:false in my webpack configuration.

Note how all the paths have "auto" in front and return http404. Note that I cleared all caches on Chrome's "Application" tab. The same happens in an incognito tab.

[image: auto paths]

When open a new tab and remove the "auto", it works fine:

[image: works fine without auto]

The service worker file with the injected manifest shows that "auto" is part of the urls:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? I'm starting to consider writing a service worker from scratch and ditching workbox, but I'd obviously rather use workbox if I can get it to work properly.

### The code:

I use the workbox-webpack-plugin to inject the precache manifest in my service worker, like so:

```
import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching';
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {CacheFirst} from 'workbox-strategies';

// Use the imported Workbox libraries to implement caching,
// routing, and other logic:
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || []);

registerRoute(
    ({request}) => request.destination === 'image',
    new CacheFirst({cacheName: 'images'}),
);
```

My webpack.config.js looks as follows, nothing fancy:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    watch: false,
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}, {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                'file-loader',
            ],
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Prototype webpack + react + workbox usage',
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
            'meta': {
                'viewport': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0',
                'charset': 'UTF-8'
            }
        }),
        new InjectManifest({
            swSrc: './service-worker.js',
            swDest: './workbox-sw-generated.js',
        })
    ]
};
```

My index.html is pretty straight-forward as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
              navigator.serviceWorker.register('/workbox-sw-generated.js')
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="index"></section>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "simple_webpack_boilerplate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A ready to use simple webpack boilerplate for react",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "author": "Willem",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.11.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.11.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "7.10.4",
        "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.1.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "4.4.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
        "webpack": "^5.0.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "16.13.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2649#issuecomment-708392517. It's due to new behavior in `webpack` v5.x

Answer (score 3):

The problem here was that workbox-webpack-plugin v5 was not compatible with webpack v5, which had just been released. The solution was to use webpack v4 instead.

Comment: Relevant issue on github: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2649 . It's fixed in 6.0.0-rc